# some jquery codes causing my site to freeze

Tags: jquery

My code is suppose to make 3 different divs fade in and out one at a time but for some reason it keeps freezing my site, im not sure what the problem is or where to begin to fix it.

```
    function randomString(length) {
      var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
      var str = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
      }
      return str;
    }
    var rnd = randomString(8);

    jQuery(function($) {
      $(".rnd").replaceWith(rnd);


      $(".example").hide().each(function(i,e){
        $(e).before($('<a class="show-code" href="#">Show code &raquo;</a>').
                      click(function(ev) {
                        $(e).slideToggle();
                        $(this).hide();
                        ev.preventDefault();
                      }));
      });
    });
      jQuery(function(jQuery){
      jQuery("#userandquery").tweet({
        count: 1,
        query: "from:groovetheglobe http",
        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
      });
      jQuery("#userandquery2").tweet({
        count: 2,
        query: "from:groovetheglobe http",
        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
      });
      jQuery("#userandquery3").tweet({
        count: 3,
        query: "from:groovetheglobe http",
        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
      });
    });

function pulse_hide1(){
    jQuery("#userandquery").fadeOut(300);
    jQuery("#userandquery-bottom").fadeOut(300);
}

function pulse_hide2(){
    jQuery("#userandquery2").fadeOut(300);
    jQuery("#userandquery2-bottom").fadeOut(300);
}

function pulse_hide3(){
    jQuery("#userandquery3").fadeOut(300);
    jQuery("#userandquery3-bottom").fadeOut(300);
}

function pulse_show1(){
    jQuery("#userandquery").fadeIn(300);
    jQuery("#userandquery-bottom").fadeIn(300);
}

function pulse_show2(){
    jQuery("#userandquery2").fadeIn(300);
    jQuery("#userandquery2-bottom").fadeIn(300);
}

function pulse_show3(){
    jQuery("#userandquery3").fadeIn(300);
    jQuery("#userandquery3-bottom").fadeIn(300);
}

function call_pulse_hide(){
    setTimeout("pulse_hide1()",1000);
    setTimeout("pulse_hide2()",3000);
    setTimeout("pulse_hide3()",3000);
}

function call_pulse_show(){
    pulse_show1();
    setTimeout("pulse_show2()",3000);
    setTimeout("pulse_show3()",3000);
}

function pulse_function(){
    while(true){
        call_pulse_hide();
        call_pulse_show();
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
/*jQuery('#fadeout').fadeOut(300);
jQuery('#fadein').delay(400).fadeIn(300);*/
pulse_function();
//alert("document done");
});
```

Comment: any chance we can get a fiddle or some html to go with it? Quick guess would be that there is an error somewhere that is causing javascript to stop running.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some other issues, but it'll be freezing because of this function:

```
function pulse_function(){
   while(true){
      call_pulse_hide();
      call_pulse_show();
   }
}
```

You've got an endless loop that doesn't leave the browser with time to do anything else (though modern browsers tend to kill such JS and give the user a warning about a long-running script).

Instead of the `while(true)` you should use `setInterval` so that your code doesn't hog all the processing time:

```
function pulse_function() {
   call_pulse_hide();
   call_pulse_show();
}
setInterval(pulse_function, 3000);
```

That will call your function every 3000ms. You may want to take the `setTimeout`s out of `call_pulse_hide` and `call_pulse_show` and just control the timing from the `setInterval`.

Another option is to get rid of `pulse_function` altogether, and in your document.ready handler call `call_pulse_hide()` directly. Then update `call_pulse_hide` and `call_pulse_show` so that they repeatedly call each other via a sort of tag-team `setTimeout`:

```
function call_pulse_hide(){
   setTimeout("pulse_hide1()",1000);
   setTimeout("pulse_hide2()",3000);
   setTimeout("pulse_hide3()",3000);

   setTimeout(call_pulse_show, 3000); // <--- new bit
}

function call_pulse_show(){
   pulse_show1();
   setTimeout("pulse_show2()",3000);
   setTimeout("pulse_show3()",3000);

   setTimeout(call_pulse_hide, 3000); // <--- new bit
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   call_pulse_hide();
}
```

For the latter option again you might want to remove the existing `setTimeout`s from within `call_pulse_hide` and `call_pulse_show`, and just control the timing via the new `setTimeout`s I've added to make them call each other with a delay.

(Note: The code I've added uses a more desirable syntax for `setTimeout` where instead of passing a string of JS code you pass in a function reference - note that for the function-reference syntax you don't include parentheses after the function name. You should look into doing that whenever you use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.)

Comment: Thank you for replying, your code works however my div tags dont fadein and out anymore

Answer (score 1):

this is giving you the problem. `while(true)` will always execute even if the two function calls inside it is not finish yet. So, what's happening is that the two functions are being called more than what you really wanted at a given time. Imagine that!

```
function pulse_function(){
    while(true){ // <----- infinite loop.... O_O
        call_pulse_hide();
        call_pulse_show();
    }
}
```